# Master page css files should not be a part of a particular child page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I don't want bootstrap files in a particular child page even these are in master page of asp.net

Answer (score 0):

You will need two masterpages in such cases. - Or - you can detect the url in the masterpage page load and set some sort of a flag. Use this flag in the markup to determine whether to load the stylsheet or not.

Ideally, I would go with the first option as it is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this on your master page, you'd have to wrap it in a conditional, then make that conditional false on the page that you don't want it. You don't give much detail, but assuming you're using C# and regular WebForms, something like this would do it:

```
**Site.Master**
<% if (ShouldHaveBootstrap) { %>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="whatever.css">
<% } %>

**Site.Master.cs**
private bool _shouldHaveBootstrap = true;
public bool ShouldHaveBootstrap { 
    get { return _shouldHaveBootstrap; }
    set { _shouldHaveBootstrap = value; }
}

**SomeOtherPage.aspx.cs**
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ((Site_Master)Master).ShouldHaveBootstrap = false;
}
```